# Symfony 2 upload file simple form

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload

Hello I want simple upload no database for now.

Inside of controller:

```
public function UploadAction(Request $request)
{

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder( array('csrf_protection' => false))
        ->add('file', 'file')
        ->add('Send', 'submit')
        ->getForm();

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $extension = $file->guessExtension();
        if (!$extension) {
            // extension cannot be guessed
            $extension = 'bin';
        }
        $file->move('blah', rand(1, 99999).'.'.$extension);
    }

    return $this->render(
        'FelekFosBundle:Plik:Upload.html.twig',
        array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        )
    );

}
```

Also I want to disable `csrf_protection` still code used seems not working.

Form is rendering well except `csrf_protection`. Still it's not preform any upload action. And I get errors.

> csrf_message The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the
>   form.

Comment: did you try to add `'csrf_field_name' => '_token'` to default options?

Comment: I'am not using any type for this build form i want to be as simple as possible. so i Don't know were to put it.

Comment: by doing `$form = $this->createFormBuilder( array('csrf_protection' => false))` you already are defining default option (such as `array('csrf_protection' => false)` is a default option, you can add another option to that array)

Comment: OK SOLVED 1 Think missing     before form validation $form->handleRequest($request);

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `$form->handleRequest($request);` before testing your `form_validity`.
The form isn't submited if you don't [call](http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/Form/FormInterface.html#method_handleRequest) `handleRequest`.

Options is on argument 2 of createFormBuilder method. Maybe

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder( null, array('csrf_protection' => false))
```

could be better. Take a look [here](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.html#method_createFormBuilder)

Comment: Yes i post solution in comment before :),Thanks